# Javascript and jquery resize event not working in IE Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, resize

I don't know what i am doing wrong but my onresize works fine in firefox but is not working in IE.

```
$(window).bind('resize', function () {resize1()}); 
window.onresize= function(){resize1()};
body.onresize= function(){resize1()};
$(window).resize(function(){resize1()});
```

I have tried all four of these and all works fine in ff but none of them work in IE.  What am i doing wrong.

My resize1 function looks like this:

```
function resize1(){
var w = $(window).height();
var h = $('.header').height();
var ht = (w-h);
document.getElementById('div').style.height=ht +"px";

}
```

My ultimate goal is to have the div resize when someone resizes the window by dragging a corner.  Again works fine in FF but not working in IE.  Thanks for your help.

When i call the function using "onload" it works fine it just doesn't fire when using the onresize event.  So when i load the page the div is the correct size but then when i resize it doesn't fire the function again.  So it seems to be something with the event oneresize not being recognized by IE. ??

Comment: In IE7 and below the window.resize even when div's are resized as well and depending on your flavor of IE there is a security rule that will prevent the resize from happening after the window.resize. I don't know if this was resolved in IE8+ but depending on your settings IE8 will behave like IE7 so it might still affect you. You might check out: http://ecmascript.stchur.com/2006/08/20/beating-the-ie-resize-bug/#more-23

Comment: Found my problem.  I was calling all of these functions at the bottom of my page because i have to wait for the divs to load in order to call the functions on those elements.  But when i use the resize event it was not triggering the event (im still not sure why but at least i found the fix).  All i did was cut and paste the resize function to my header and it works fine.  So i guess all i had to do was call the on resize function in the header not below my body.  Thanks all who helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).resize(function(){resize1()});

function resize1(){

var w = $(window).height();
var h = $('.header').height();
var ht = w-h;

$('#div').height(ht);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IE? 8.0 and earlier get values without `px`
Try `document.getElementById('div').style.height=ht;`

Comment: So i don't think that is the issue because when i call the function "onload" it works fine it just doesn't fire when using the onresize event.  So when i load the page the div is the correct size but then when i resize it doesn't fire the function again.  So it seems to be something with the event oneresize not being recognized by IE. ??